# Using Eclox in Code Composer Studuo (CCS)

Tags: embedded

With every new CCS-Version, I always search on how to activate documentation with Doxygen.
I think I'm not the only one, so I just wanted to show it to everyone again. (And for me if I have to install a never CCS again)

To use doxygen I am using the eclox-Plugin for eclipse.
The installation ist quite easy and described here https://anb0s.github.io/eclox/

But the tricky part is, how the activate the documentation while coding so that the documentation body for a function will automatically appear if you type /** one line above the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside CCS you have to go to Window->Preferences, make sure the advanced settings are displayed (button at the bottom). Then go to C/C++->Editor and change the property of the "Documentation tool comments" to Doxygen.

Now you can type /** over a function to automatically generate the documentation body like this.

```
/**
 * 
 * @param pvData
 * @param usLength
 * @param ulStatusFlag
 * @return
 */
uint16_t IPCLiteLtoRGetResult (void *pvData, uint16_t usLength, uint32_t ulStatusFlag)
```

Maybe this will help somebody (most likely myself) in the future.

Comment: Thanks. Can confirm this solution works in CCS v10.4 after install Eclox